# Python PIL combine images results in an all black image

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I am trying to use the following to combine three images into one using PIL and Python

```
import sys
from PIL import Image

images = map(Image.open, ['ib1.jpg', 'ib2.jpg', 'ib3.jpg'])
widths, heights = zip(*(i.size for i in images))

total_width = sum(widths)
max_height = max(heights)

new_im = Image.new('RGB', (total_width, max_height))

x_offset = 0
for im in images:
  new_im.paste(im, (x_offset,0))
  x_offset += im.size[0]

new_im.save('test.jpg')
```

The test.jpg image seems to be the correct height but the image is totally black.

What can I try next?

Comment: Could you post the actual three images you're using?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

2016-03-29 Edit:

`map` in Python 3 returns a generator, and it got exhausted in your `zip` function call, so the generator just generates an empty list in your for loop.
You can change

```
images = map(Image.open, ['ib1.jpg', 'ib2.jpg', 'ib3.jpg'])
```

to

```
images = list(map(Image.open, ['ib1.jpg', 'ib2.jpg', 'ib3.jpg']))
```

It should work as you expect.

Older post:

I have tested on my machine and it seems that the same code executed in Python 2(2.7.11 on my machine) works as you expects but Python 3(3.5.1) don't. I am figureing out why.